# Estimating better performing variation with unkown sample size

Tags: time-series, experiment-design, count-data

Scenario: We are in the app business and trying to optimize for downloads in the app store. Things like the shown screenshots, the text, the icon etc. can be changed and will have an influence on the number of downloads.

Example:
Setup 1, downloads in a week: 100
Setup 2, downloads in a week: 110

I believe that this differs from normal A/B testing on websites, as we unfortunately do not know the sample size, i.e. how many people looked at the app profile. We only know how many decided to download and that the timeframe is the same, assuming that all others things stayed equal during the two time periods, maybe we can at least estimate the two sample sizes to be equal.

Still it should be possible to infer something from these very limited numbers. Possibly after estimating a few things about the sample size and the population in general. Another difference to the A/B testing is that the variations are carried out in sequence and not in parallel. Of course, at this point we can only assume that factors other than what we changed have stayed constant.

Can anyone give pointers as to how get the most out of this limited data? A rough estimate of which variation is better by which confidence interval is all we need

Answer (score 1):

If you only have measurements for two one-week-long sequential periods, there's probably not much you can do to get a signal from it--there's just too much noise between the two weeks.

However, if you can randomize the app profile between A and B more quickly, and measure the number of downloads each time, then you can still get a proper randomized design. That is, instead of having the data points

```
setup   time        downloads
A       12/1-12/7   100
B       12/8-12/14  110
```

you might have the data points

```
setup   time    downloads
A       12/1    10
A       12/2    8
B       12/3    11
A       12/4    3
A       12/5    7
A       12/6    12
B       12/7    8
B       12/8    5
```

You can then think about whether `A` or `B` points have a significantly higher number of downloads per day. This becomes more powerful the faster you can re-randomize the profile, since there will be less confounding noise on a minute-to-minute basis than day-to-day, and less day-to-day than week-to-week, etc. (As @whuber noted below in response to an earlier version, you basically need multiple observations for each profile in order to apply a probability model to the data.)

(Note that in this scenario your data are unlikely to be normally-distributed, so you should be careful with your hypothesis testing, perhaps using a [bootstrap](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bootstrapping_(statistics)).)

If you can't re-randomize it fast enough, you will need a long time to get enough [statistical power](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Statistical_power). You should calculate how many data points you expect to need beforehand based on the distribution of downloads-per-time-period that you currently have, so that you don't just keep running the experiment until you have a significant result and then stop immediately; this will bias your results.

Comment: With the design described by the OP, there is no statistical power at all because (a) there is no identifiable probability model that can be applied and (b) due to lack of any controls at all, all the results will be irretrievably confounded with all sorts of possible systematic factors. It is therefore pointless--and misleading--to compute confidence intervals, etc.  At best one might hope that a statistical power calculation could provide some guidance for designing a randomized experiment capable of producing useful results.

Comment: @whuber, I was suggesting a modification to the study design. I agree that if they merely run branch A for a week and then branch B for a week there's not much information that could be extracted. Sorry if it wasn't clear. I'll edit the original post to clarify.

Comment: Got it, thanks for setting my head straight. I am using the daily randomization design on two of the factors, but they are unfortunately not that significant. For the others it just isn't possible without extending the setup (having more systems to administrate and monitor). I'll reconsider/research and possibly get back to you. Thank you again for the input!